# DataGridView multiselection

Tags: c#, datagridview, charts

I can't seem to exit from my loop..

I have a project where I'm loading in a collection of records, (one collection each category.)

I'm showing this data in a DataGridView, from which I'm supposed to be able to select a record in the DataGridView and show it in a chart.

I managed to get it working by using a switch (case 0, case 1, etc etc as per the id of the selected row.)

Obviously this prevents me to be able to select more than 1 row at a time...and is not very functional.. Are there any other systems I could use?

Comment: A `Winforms DataGridView`  has an option `Multiselect` and you can loop over the `SelectedItems` collection.

Comment: I'm sorry....i didn't think there was difference between datagridview and gridview. anyway, it is winforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to set `MultiSelect = true`.

Then you can loop over the selected rows:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    // do something with the row..
}
```

Now the user can use the normal key (shift and/or control) to create a more or less complex multi-selection.

Or, as Kailash suggests, you could add a `CheckBoxColumn` and loop over all rows, processing only those where the checkbox is checked..

Also note that there are various `SelectionModes` to choose from. `FullrowSelect` may be nicest for the user.

To make the chart updates happen code (and hook up) the  `SelectionChanged` event of the `DataGridView`! Make sure to clear the `Points` of the `Chart` `Series` you use before adding new data points!

Comment: Thanks! I can't make it work yet  (event is not triggering), but it seems a good solution!

Comment: To automate use the SelectionChanged event!